# VB.NET Regular Expressions, matching escape characters

Tags: regex, vb.net

Ok, so I hate asking RegEx questions because I like to figure them out myself usually. Plus it gets fairly annoying on the other end because people probably ask stupid "why dont you just look it up" questions all the time.

My requirement is simple. I want to use `Regex.Replace` to replace a Match with a context sensitive value. I use the `MatchEvaluator` for this. But to make things simpler lets say I'm matching `%v`

I want `%v` to be escapable, so if I use `\%v` it will not match. Anything else should match.

The pattern I came up with is this: `(?:[^\\]|^)%v`

It basically matches `%v` if it occurs at the beginning of the string, or if it follows any character except `\`. It doesn't capture the first part of the expression.

I know this isn't the "right" way to do it. But it worked just fine until I noticed that when I use this pattern in a replace, it includes the character before `%v` in the replacement(duh, right?)

So, if I have `ThisIsAValue:%v` and I do `Regex.Replace`, replacing with the string `Value`, my result will be `ThisIsAValueValue` instead of `ThisIsAValue:Value`

I've tried googling this but the fact that "escape character" is so heavy in RegEx, all the results are geared towards the USAGE of escape characters instead of picking them out with a pattern.

Any RegEx savvy people know how I can do this correctly?

Comment: As a side note, a change you can make (which may or may not make the expression simpler to you) is to change `[^\\]|^` to `[^\\]?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually put the start character back in, by capturing it and including it in the replace value:

```
Regex.Replace("ThisIsAValue:%v", "([^\\]|^)%v", "$1Value")
```

Comment: Hah, so simple. I was so hung up on doin it in the pattern I didnt even think of the obvious.

Comment: Thank you sir, you win an internet.

Comment: I was going to suggest doing a look-behind, but this is really simple!